# How to import leveldb in Python 3.5 on Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, dll, package, leveldb

I struggled a while to install leveldb package in Python 3.5 on Windows.

https://github.com/happynear/py-leveldb-windows gives some clues on how to install the package. However, even though following all the instruction in the post, I still got a following error when I imported the package leveldb in Ipython prompt:

```
import leveldb

  Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-16-4427bf69c6fb>", line 1, in <module>
   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please make it more detail, give what you've done so the others can give the alternative solution else to do.

Answer (score 1):

The compiled pyd file at https://github.com/happynear/py-leveldb-windows is for Python 3.6 as of 18.03.2019. I had the same error as the OP when trying to use it with Python 3.7. Uninstalling 3.7 and installing 3.6 made it work.